# How to create a product ID in Google Play / AppStore via API

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

The reality today is that in order to create a new product ID in the app stores, a dev needs to create a new product ID in the game / app server and then create the matching product in the stores. This is an error prone process which takes time. 
I'd like to create all the packages in one place and update the stores using an API - is it possible? Do you know any other way other than doing it manually?

Thanks!

Comment: There is "Produce" from Fastlane, which works for iOS apps. They're working on bringing in more Android support, but I think at the moment it's not working for Google Play. https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane

Comment: Thank you - will check it out

Comment: Did either of you get anywhere with doing this? There is an API now, but doesn't seem to support creation, or at least it's not documented.